# Highcharts column percentage stacked chart worked in v 2.3.5 broken with v 3.0.2

Tags: highcharts

With version 2.3.5 of Highcharts, I have a column chart set to percentage and stacked that displays 4 columns of values for black, cyan, magenta, and yellow ink level percentages out of 100 and individual colors for each column. I also stack a series of gray values on top of these to fill out the remaining percentage out of 100 to the top of the container. I set x axis labels to the color percentages.

I set `plotOptions.series.colorByPoint: true`

This worked perfectly with v 2.3.5 but with v 3.0.2 I still see the x axis percentages but all I see is 4 gray bars filling the container. No matter how I rearrange the colors or series I can't get the chart to display properly.

```
$(function () {
    var row1values = {
        "Black": 78,
        "Cyan": 55,
        "Magenta": 33,
        "Yellow": 90
    };

    var row1inverseValues = {
        "Black": 22,
        "Cyan": 45,
        "Magenta": 77,
        "Yellow": 10
    };

    var options = {
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        chart: {
            renderTo: "container",
            type: "column",
            animation: false,
            spacingTop: 7,
            spacingRight: 0,
            spacingLeft: 0,
            backgroundColor: "#fff"
        },
        colors: ["#f5f5f5", "#f5f5f5", "#f5f5f5", "#f5f5f5", "#282521", "#91cfcf", "#be4e95", "#f2f000"],
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [row1values.Black, row1values.Cyan, row1values.Magenta, row1values.Yellow],
            lineWidth: 0,
            tickLength: 0,
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            gridLineWidth: 0
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                colorByPoint: true,
                pointPadding: 0.02,
                groupPadding: 0.02
            },
            column: {
                stacking: "percent",
                animation: false,
                enableMouseTracking: false,
                borderWidth: 0,
                shadow: false
            },
            area: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [row1inverseValues.Black, row1inverseValues.Cyan, row1inverseValues.Magenta, row1inverseValues.Yellow]
        }, {
            data: [row1values.Black, row1values.Cyan, row1values.Magenta, row1values.Yellow]
        }]
    };

    new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

v 2.3.5
http://jsfiddle.net/SixEight/rptEf/

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/2.3.5/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>
```

v 3.0.2
http://jsfiddle.net/SixEight/KDG5y/

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colors define order of series colors, not each point. So in your case, I advice to set color for each point in second serie.

```
{
                        y: row1values.Black,
                        color:'#282521'
                    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KDG5y/7/

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#colors